# Modify previous item in iteration

Tags: java, android, iterator

In my Android application, I have a list of `Appointment` objects that contain appointment-related information. A `ListView` then gets populated with a selection of these appointments, sorted by time.

I have written my own custom adapter for this listview in order to be able to insert 'free-time' appointments where there is a gap between appointments.

This is my code so far:

```
ArrayList<Appointment> appointments = new ArrayList<Appointment>();
// populate arraylist here
ListIterator<Appointment> iter = appointments.listIterator();
DateTime lastEndTime = new DateTime();
int count = 0;
while (iter.hasNext()){
    Appointment appt = iter.next();
    lastEndTime = appt.endDateTime;
    // Skips first iteration
    if (count > 0)
    {
        if (lastEndTime.isAfter(appt.startDateTime))
        {
            if (iter.hasNext())
            {
                Appointment freeAppt = new Appointment();
                freeAppt.isFreeTime = true;
                freeAppt.subject = "Free slot";
                freeAppt.startDateTime = lastEndTime;
                freeAppt.endDateTime = lastEndTime.minusMinutes(-60); // Currently just set to 60 minutes until I solve the problem
                iter.add(freeAppt);
            }
        }
    }
    count++;
}
DiaryAdapter adapter = new DiaryAdapter(this, R.layout.appointment_info, appointments);
```

The issue that I'm having is a logic one. I've been racking my brains to try and find a solution, but it seems like my lack of java knowledge is holding me back a little here.

In order to know when the 'free-time' appointment ends, I must know when the next 'real' appointment starts. But I can't get that information until the next cycle of the iterator, by which point the 'free-time' appointment is no longer in context.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this particular case, the *simplest* option is probably not to use an iterator at all. You're already tied to a `List` (rather than just any `Iterable`) so you might as well just keep a counter and use `get()`.

Alternatively, given that you're using a `ListIterator`, you could use the [`previous()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html#previous%28%29) method to get back to the previous item. It's all a matter of what you find simpler though - my guess is that it'll be easier to understand the code using explicit indexes. (It means you can remove the `if (count > 0)` part too...)

Comment: And there I was thinking I was so clever using an iterator! When in actual fact, a counter was my first thought.

Comment: Thank you for the extra info. The advantage I found to using an iterator was that I was able to use `iter.add()` to insert a new row at the current position. Is there a good equivalent to this if I'm just using a counter/index approach?

Comment: @Teifi: You'd just use `List.add` with an index.

Comment: Ah I didn't see that overload. I assume that automatically pushes all following entries up one index?

Comment: @Teifi: Yup. I'd expect the `ListIterator` implementation returned by `ArrayList` to effectively end up calling `add` like this :)

Comment: Much appreciated, Jon :)

Answer (score 3):

Iterate using an index instead of an iterator and retrieve elements with `appointments.get()`. You can then make changes to the list at earlier indexes. You just have to do a little bookkeeping to keep the indexing in sync with any list changes.